# Scale huge axis in R for plotting

Tags: r

I have a huge file I load into one vector

`y = scan("my_file)`

My x axis is also really huge, lets say it is in range of `x=1:5000000`

My question is now how can I scale my plot so that I actually can see something?So far I am doing the following

UPDATE:

[image: the plot i generate by using the log="x" optioin]

```
plot(x, y, log="x", pch=".")
```

However only the logarithm is not enough. Can i somehow scale the x more, like taking a sqrt or something, and if yes how? Sorry this may be a simple question but I am really new to R..

I am not sure how to add a file, but the file I a using to load into vector y is as I said, only 5 million values of entry 1,2 or 0: so

y=c(1,0,1,....................)

the x axis as I mentioned above.

The second thing I tried was:

```
zerotwo <- data.frame(x, y)
ggplot(aes(x, y, fill=as.factor(y)), data=zerotwo) + geom_tile() + scale_x_continuous(trans='log2') + geom_tile()
```

But here also the fill=as.factor doesnt do its job[image]

Comment: Please include the shortest code and data necessary to reproduce this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In what way are you not seeing anything?  Is this really a problem about the axes or is it that there are so many points that the plot is too crowded and you can't see anything? Are there outliers that make it so that much of the graph is empty in order to include outliers? Maybe it would help to post a picture of your current graph so that we could see what is going wrong.

Comment: I have added the figure .The problem is - so the thing I wanna see are clear separation between the values, so  where the bars are at value 1 and at 2.  Like this the values look like they overlap

Comment: If I were you, I'd probably superimpose three histograms, one for each value 0,1 and 2, and see how they overlap.

Comment: Two things to try:  1. Add jitter with `plot(x, jitter(y), log="x", pch=".")`  And  2. Use transparency so that high densities of points are darker than low densities.  `plot(x, y, log="x", pch=".", col="#00000022")`

Comment: the jitter is nice but however the transparency is not working

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to rely on color-coding to encode the value, and use the y-axis to put the data into different rows. 5m tiles on the x-axis is a bit much for `ggplot`, but 50*100k works ok if the plot size is large enough.read from left to right, then top to bottom.

```
# create test data
zerototwo <- data.frame(position=1:5000000, value=sample(0:2, 5000000, replace=TRUE))

# for your data: zerototwo <- data.frame(position=1:length(y), value=y)

zerototwo$row <- floor((zerototwo$position -1)/100000)
zerototwo$rowpos <- (zerototwo$position - 1) %% 100000

ggplot(aes(x=rowpos, y=row, fill=as.factor(value)), data=zerototwo) + 
  geom_tile(height=0.9) + scale_y_reverse()
```

[image: in rows]